# How to keep order when parsing reddit with praw?

Tags: parsing, reddit, praw

I'm trying praw for parsing [this reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1irtkq/taxi_drivers_whats_the_deepest_secret_youve/?sort=top). And I found that this code doesn't save the order:

```
sm = reddit.submission(url="https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1irtkq/taxi_drivers_whats_the_deepest_secret_youve/")
sm.comment_sort = 'top'
sm.comments.replace_more(0)

allComments = sm.comments.list()
for i in allComments[1].replies:
  print(i.body[:10])
```

Is it possible to fix that and get the same order for all trees?
[image]

Comment: What comment sort are you using in the web browser? You should set the same comment sort in PRAW to ensure the same order

Comment: `top`. It is the same. You can see it in my link `https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1irtkq/taxi_drivers_whats_the_deepest_secret_youve/?sort=top`

Comment: @jarhill0 Any idea why this is happening? This is not the only one difference between `praw` result and the real browser.

Comment: Both Old and New Reddit agree with the API on the order of the comments, and this can be confirmed by inspecting the scores: https://new.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1irtkq/taxi_drivers_whats_the_deepest_secret_youve/cb7fbku/?sort=top https://old.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1irtkq/taxi_drivers_whats_the_deepest_secret_youve/cb7fbku/?sort=top

Comment: Notice that your screenshot has a comment with score 15 above one with score 103. That's not being sorted by hot.

Comment: I suppose it's a bug of reddit site. It shows different versions: left - incognito signed out (exactly the same link and browser settings as in my post), right - signed in. https://ibb.co/YfptfyV

Comment: Perhaps you have a setting in your preferences that is overriding the sort. Either way, it seems like your question has been resolved.